# Sencha Touch 2 - Select a photo

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Sencha and trying to build a simple flow where the user needs to select a photo to proceed to "step 2". The selection of the photo can either come from a new camera capture or from an existing photo.

Here's my code to capture the photo:

```
    Ext.device.Camera.capture({
        success: function(image) {
            Ext.create('myapp.view.PreviewImage', {
                title: 'Test photo',
                description: 'Testing a camera capture',    
                src: image,
                fullscreen: true
            });
        },
        quality: 75,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        destination: 'data'
    });
```

I'm waiting for my iPhone to arrive in the mail so I can test the camera (since the iOS simulator doesn't have hardware support) so the above code may or may not work. My question is, what's the alternative - I took the above code from the example on the Sencha Touch 2 docs for `Ext.device.Camera` and I see they're storing it in `data`. I noticed on some other examples that `data` will be a folder sibling to `app`.

Is it possible with the current Sencha Touch 2 device api to browse photos on the device? I've read some posts on the Sencha forums about using PhoneGap as the native device wrapper but with Sencha Touch 2 it has its own native packager and device API so I'm thinking I should be able to contain the entire app here.

According to their docs (which seem to be incomplete) located here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Camera

> Both the Sencha Packager and PhoneGap implementations will use the
>   native camera functionality to take **or select** a photo. The Simulator
>   implementation will simply return fake images.

The only two methods mentioned in the docs for Ext.device.Camera are `capture()` and `getInitialConfig()`

Can someone please point me to a snippet or provide me with a simple example to browse existing photos on the device?

**UPDATE** - Per new docs referenced in the answer, here's the `source` property specs:

```
The source of where the image should be taken. Available options are:

album - prompts the user to choose an image from an album
camera - prompts the user to take a new photo
library - prompts the user to choose an image from the library
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `source` property of the capture method.

Documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.camera.Abstract-method-capture

```
Ext.device.Camera.capture({
    source: 'library',
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that link, I see it now